# Real life implementation of Enums

Tags: java, enums

I have recently learnt that Enums are kind of data types just like int, char etc. But in Enums we can define our on data types. But my question what is the necessity for user defined data types. I would be helpful if an example of real world scenario is provided.

Comment: SO is for specific question with a definitive answer. You might prefer to use a forum like Quora. All the same here is a non-trivial example https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/wire/WireType.java

Comment: Every new class is user defined data type. Nothing new for Enum...

Comment: When you need a predefined list of values you should use an enum, way cleaner and more readable.

Comment: @AdnanIsajbegovic But I can create an array for the same. Why use an enum for the purpose.

Comment: read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Answer (score 1):

User data types are like building blocks. We have the limited number of such standard blocks (e.g. primitive types), therefore, we need to expand them by building our own classes. Enum is a class with predefined values that cannot be changed.

For example,

```
public enum ProfessionType { DOCTOR, MANAGER, SELLER; }
```

We guarantee that it will create only one instance of `DOCTOR`, `MANAGER` and so on. Imagine, we are going to create a doctor type manually (in this case, `ProfessionType` is a class)

```
ProfessionType doctor1 = new ProfessionType("doctor");
ProfessionType doctor2 = new ProfessionType("doctor");
```

Which one is better? Am I a doctor of `doctor1` type or of the second one?

Answer (score 1):

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be
>   a set of predefined constants.

Here is some code that shows you how to use the Day enum defined above:

```
public class EnumTest {
    Day day;

    public EnumTest(Day day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public void tellItLikeItIs() {
        switch (day) {
            case MONDAY:
                System.out.println("Mondays are bad.");
                break;

            case FRIDAY:
                System.out.println("Fridays are better.");
                break;

            case SATURDAY: case SUNDAY:
                System.out.println("Weekends are best.");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so.");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumTest firstDay = new EnumTest(Day.MONDAY);
        firstDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest thirdDay = new EnumTest(Day.WEDNESDAY);
        thirdDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest fifthDay = new EnumTest(Day.FRIDAY);
        fifthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest sixthDay = new EnumTest(Day.SATURDAY);
        sixthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest seventhDay = new EnumTest(Day.SUNDAY);
        seventhDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Mondays are bad.
Midweek days are so-so.
Fridays are better.
Weekends are best.
Weekends are best.
```

for more details check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we are asked to sum the position number of each alphabet of a sentence that was sent to a function

**Example:**

> A=1,B=2,C=3....so on

so instead of using switch each char in loop and then add its value we could use Enum here , Because all values are incremented by 1 by default

```
 public enum Alpha
    {
        A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z
    }

    // based on the input
    public static int Count(string name="")
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (char item in name)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.ToString()))
                sum += (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Alpha), item.ToString().ToUpper());


        }
        return sum;
    }
```